# Bash Script to seperate a line contains "^A"

Tags: linux, bash, shell

My file contains a line like

```
39=2^A40=1^A54=2
```

I want to get like this

```
39=2,40=1,54=2
```

How can iIseparate value if line contains ^A`` in Bash Script?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? You want delete all occurrence of `^A` in the file?

Comment: are the `^A`s literal string `"^A"`?

Comment: no, i want separate all value by "^A" . i dont want to delete all occurrance of ^A.

Comment: while i opening the file using vi editor that time i have seen value of file is separated by "^A"

Comment: @user2266543 that doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Specifically, the non-printable ASCII character `\x01` ("Start of Heading") would be *displayed* in vi as `^A`, but it's not a literal `^A`.

Comment: You can test that with `printf '^A\x01\n' | vim -`, or have a look at the output of some hexdump tool on your string, `printf '^A\x01\n' | od`.

Comment: Helpful search keyword for googling: "caret notation"

Comment: Dear user2266543, what @BenjaminW. and @Kent mean is that sometimes files in linux show characters like `^A` and `^M` or `^I` but they do not represent a combination of caret and a letter, but what is called a [Caret notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret_notation) of a control character. If you type the command `file filename` what does it return. If it states 'ASCII file', you are safe, if it says something else it represents caret notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With sed you can just swap out your `^A` delimiter with a comma:

```
echo "39=2^A40=1^A54=2" | sed 's/\^A/,/g'
```

With `awk` you can do:

```
echo "39=2^A40=1^A54=2" | awk 'BEGIN{FS="[\\^][A]";OFS=","}{$1=$1}1'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sed` in this way:

```
echo '39=2^A40=1^A54=2' | sed 's/\^A/,/g'
39=2,40=1,54=2
```

Answer (score 1):

if the `^A`s were literal strings, other answers should help. Just accept one, and I am gonna remove this answer. If  the answers didn't help you, you can try this:

## Note

all `^A` below, you should type in this way: 
**`Ctrl-V ctrl-A`**

---

### in vim

you mentioned "open it in vi", you can in vim do:

```
:%s/^A/,/g
```

### with sed

```
sed 's/^A/,/g' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo 39=2^A40=1^A54=2 | awk '{sub(/\^A40=1\^A/,",40=1,")}1'
39=2,40=1,54=2
```